# Как указать считываемый размер в scanf?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

`scanf`-ом можно считать определенное кол-во символов, к примеру, с помощью `"%10s"`.

Как считать количество символов из переменной? Не используя при этом просто `"%s"` или `fgets`.

Допустим,

```
int count;
fscanf(stdin, "%d", count);
char* name = new char [count];
fscanf (stdin, /*как указать считываемое кол-во символов count? */, name);
```

Comment: @AlexF, можно поподробнее как это сделать?

Comment: @AlexF, большое спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) − никак.

В функции [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) есть похожее поведение − можно дополнительным аргументом указать *минимальную ширину поля* или *точность преобразования*. Пример с минимальной шириной поля:

```
char str[] = "abc";
printf("%*s\n", 10, str); // обратите внимание на звездочку (*)
printf("%10s\n", str);
```

---

Можете, как @Alex F [посоветовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-scanf/1104605#comment1903489_1104579) в комментариях, генерировать строку формата с помощью, например, [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
const size_t count = 3;
char name[count + 1];

const size_t fmt_length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%%%zus", count);
char fmt[fmt_length + 1];
snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%%zus", count);

scanf(fmt, name);
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно выделять память под строку формата? Довольно очевидно, что 20 байт за глаза хватит.

Comment: А как можно совместить snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%%zus", count); с таким типом форматирования: "%*[^\"]%*c%[^\"]" ?

Comment: @AnnaErion, все `%` заменить на `%%`, и все \ на \\.

Comment: @eanmos, премного благодарна.)

Comment: @eanmos, небольшое уточнение, менять \ на \\ не нужно.

Comment: @AnnaErion, менять нужно, только на \\\ (три слэша, а не два: я в предыдущем комментарии ошибся). Иначе слэш перед кавычкой экранируется и получится другая строка. А вообще, вы, похоже, делаете что-то очень нехорошее, потому что код получается запутанным. Зачем вам вообще генерировать такой формат в run-time?. Что вам в целом нужно сделать?

Comment: @eanmos, таким образом я пытаюсь избежать переполнения буфера и потери целостности данных  при работе с scanf, а оно может быть, если считывать просто"%s" . В программе я вычисляю максимальный размер буфера строки ( у меня 2048). И уже с массивом такого размера работаю.

Comment: @Anna Erion, нет, я спрашивал про это: "%*[^\"]%*c%[^\"]".

Comment: @eanmos, считать только то, что внутри кавычек

Comment: @AnnaErion, тогда у вас немного неправильный формат. Вот, [взгляните](https://gist.github.com/Eanmos/19c50b05986bc90a8f992413b3779eee).